# About the syntax of Chisel

Tags: chisel

I am new to this.

I have some questions about the code.

What is different between these codes:

val myVec = Vec(5){Fix(width= 23)}

and

val myVec = Vec.fill(5){SInt(width = 23 )}

what does "fill" mean?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Fill" is a Scala-ism, for initializing things like lists with elements:

```
scala> val x = List.fill(3)("foo")
x: List[java.lang.String] = List(foo, foo, foo)
```

In the same vein, `Vec.fill(5){SInt(width=23)}` is returning a Chisel Vec where each of the 5 elements is set to a 23b signed integer wire.

---

However, if you are using Chisel, you should move to Chisel3 (https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki), in which the new syntax is:

```
val myVec = Wire(Vec(5, SInt(width=23)))
```

That creates a Wire of a 5-element vector made up of 23b signed integers. (In Chisel3 any wires must be explicitly wrapped).

Comment: thank for your answer , I want to ask one more question.
Can I specify one element or a range of elements of these vectors?
for example, the fifth bit of the third vector,or 4th to 10th bits of the third vector.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but all elements of the fill must be the same type. You can override individual elements later on.

Comment: So,if I want  to assign or check one bit(or a range of bits) of these vectors ,how do I do so that I can make it? Can you please give me a simple code to explain?
I am not familiar with Chisel and Scala ,thank for your patience

Comment: I recommend you look through a code base like rocket-chip and grep around for Vecs and find a scenario that matches your needs.